# Problems with SQL Azure Migration Wizard

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database, bcp

I am trying to migrate my SQL Server 2008 R2 database to Windows Azure. I am using SQLAzureMW for this. But I am getting the below errors after inserting few rows.

```
BCP Command: bcp.exe "mydatabase.dbo.tableTest" in "c:\SQLAzureMW\BCPData\dbo.tableTest.dat" -E -w -b 10000 -a 16384 -q -S SERVER.database.windows.net -U "Test@vSERVER" -P "password"
*****
01/03/2013 10:18:08--> Error  

Starting copy...
SQLState = 22003, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Numeric value out of range
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid character value for cast specification
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid character value for cast specification
10000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 10000
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]String data, right truncation
SQLState = 22008, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid date format
```

I made sure the tables script generated exactly matche with my database tables in SQL Server and the database collation is also same on both the sides.

Could you please let me know how to solve these issues?

Comment: could you show us the schemas that you're working against. What's the table in 2008 R2 and how is it defined in SQLAzureMW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to ensure that the Collation on the source and target database are identical, otherwise you will likely run into these errors.

When creating a new target DB from SQLAzure MW be careful as it may default to another Collation.